# Why is array.map nested within array.forEach so much faster (in this case) than the other way around?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a page that gives the user the ability to filter store locations by clicking on links for Region and Individual Shops nested within those Regions. Every click updates an object containing which filters have been applied, hides all the elements and then shows only the filtered set of elements.

My code in this post takes the data from the filters object and creates a CSS selector string to which the jQuery `.show()` method can applied.

I tried doing it 2 different ways thinking there wouldn't be much of a difference in performance, but to my surprise, jsbench.me showed **Solution #2** (below) to be ~90% slower, and I'm baffled as to why.

Here is the code that creates the CSS selector string for each solution. They both use the same object representing the current active filters. They can be found in [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/daveh0/pen/rNmQVxN) as well (variables are named slightly differently, but the code is the same as below).

### Example Active Filters Object

```
const filts = {
  levels: [],
  locations: {
    "new-york": ["monore", "chester", "cortalnd"],
    colorado: ["denver"],
    penn: [],
  }
};
```

### Solution 1:

```
const locs2 = filts.locations;
  const activeRegions = Object.keys(locs2);
  if(activeRegions.length) {        
    let sels2 = [];       
    activeRegions.forEach(region => {          
      const regionSelStr = `#region-holder__${region}`;
      sels2.push(regionSelStr);         
      const shops2 = locs2[region];
      if(shops2.length) {            
        const shopsSels = shops2.map(shop => `#shop-holder_${region}_${shop}`);
        sels2.push(...shopsSels);               
      } else {
        sels2.push(`${regionSelStr} .shop-holder`);
      }         
    });  
    console.log(sels2.join(','));
  }
```

### Solution 2:

```
  const locs = filts.locations;
  const regions = Object.keys(locs);
  const sels = regions.map(region => {
    const regionPart = `#region-holder__${region}`;
    let str = `${regionPart},`;
    const shopPart = locs[region];
    if(!shopPart.length) {
      str += `${regionPart} .shop-holder`;
    } else {
      shopPart.forEach((shop, i, arr) => { arr[i] = `#shop-holder_${region}_${shop}` });
      str += shopPart.join(',');
    }
    return str;
  });
  console.log(sels.join(','));
```

They each use a `.forEach()` and a `.map()` for iterating,  but is it the order in which they're used/nested? Or is it because **Solution 2** changes the value of the `filts` object when does its `Object.keys(filts.locations).map(...)`? Any ideas?

## EDIT

I changed **Solution 2** to use string interpolation (oversight on my part at first) - still ~88% slower according to jsbench.me

## EDIT 2

I changed **Solution 2** to **NOT** call `array.join` on each iteration, rather just start building up the string right in the `forEach()` and now it is the faster one by ~10%

```
  const locs = filts.locations;
  const regions = Object.keys(locs);
  const sels = regions.map(region => {
    const regionPart = `#region-holder__${region}`;
    let str = `${regionPart},`;
    const shopPart = locs[region];
    if(!shopPart.length) {
      str += `${regionPart} .shop-holder`;
    } else {
      shopPart.forEach((shop, i, arr) => { 
        str += `#shop-holder_${region}_${shop},`; 
      });
    }
    return str;
  });
  console.log(sels.join(','));
```

Comment: You're also testing the relative speed of string concatenation vs string interpolation and array joins. If you want to know the performance difference of just the `map` and `forEach`, keep everything else exactly the same.

Comment: you can test your code performance here : https://jsben.ch/

Comment: @HannaRose the OP has already used a benchmarking tool; it's in the question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - oops Solution  should have been using string interpolation as well. I'll update and test again. Will be interesting to see if that closes the gap a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between `forEach` and `map` won't really be significant, `forEach` will likely have a slight edge since it doesn't have to create a new array but that's just a guess.  The reason why your code is slower in solution 2 with `forEach` is because 1. you're using a `join` which will execute an array join on every iteration (essentially creating a factorial loop) and also 2. you're using string concatenation which will be slower than interpolation, as the comment on your question have already mentioned.  Solution 1 is just linear with a bit extra for adding new items to an array, which is negligible.

Comment: It was definitely the `array.join()`... see edits to OP